# How to check the partition alignment on an SSD drive?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

As I understand it, for SSD it's important to have partitions starting at the proper offset (i.e. correctly aligned). How can I check this offset under Windows Vista?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just run `msinfo32` and find "Partition Starting Offset". It will be in bytes, divide the number by 512 to convert into sectors.
On my SSD it is 1MB (1 048 576 bytes), but as far as i know, 128k is enough.

Comment: On my Windows 7 x64 system it is C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSInfo\msinfo32.exe

Comment: On my `Windows XP Pro` `x32` system it is `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSInfo\msinfo32.exe` too. Can't remember if it's part of the original XP install or not.

Comment: With Windows, 4k alignment is enough because NTFS does not have any periodic structure larger than the cluster size (unlike, say, ext2)

Comment: It's always msinfo32. Just type msinfo32 at a Run prompt (Windows-R). It's in your path. No need to go digging through directories.

Answer (score 6):

In Windows XP:

```
> diskpart -i <disk number>
```

should show HiddenSectors divisible by 64 and StartingOffest divisible by 32768

In Vista, 7, 8, 8.1 and 10:

```
> E:\Home>wmic partition get BlockSize, StartingOffset, Name, Index
BlockSize Index Name StartingOffset
512 0 Disk #1, Partition #0 1048576
512 1 Disk #1, Partition #1 53688139776
```

Comment: [diskpart](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300415) doesn't seem to work that way in WinXP.  can you give more details?

Comment: I had to do a convoluted series of commands on WinXP: diskpart > select disk 1 > list partition

Result:
<blockquote>
    DISKPART> list partition

     Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
      -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
    * Partition 1    Primary             49 GB    32 KB
      Partition 2    Extended           883 GB    49 GB
      Partition 3    Logical            883 GB    49 GB</blockquote>

Comment: That wmic works even on Windows 10

Answer (score 4):

You are right, but it does not work like that on Windows XP. There you can use **diskpart**:

```
diskpart -i (number of your ssd)
```

And you'll get geometry information and disk partition information.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I use the [Paragon Alignment Tool](http://www.paragon-software.com/business/partition-alignment/index.html), which comes with Paragon products, or can be bought seperately.

Answer (score 1):

To check alignment, start "wmic" with admin rights, and enter command "partition get BlockSize, StartingOffset, Name, Index"

(wmic is available in Win7, possibly Vista)

Answer (score 1):

`diskpart.exe` and `diskpar.exe` are separate utilities from Microsoft.
What is given above works with `diskpar.exe` only:

`diskpar -i x`

`x` as the drive number.
You cannot retrieve the offset using `diskpart.exe`. Use `msinfo32.exe` as described above

`diskpart.exe` started be be bundled with Windows 2003 and Vista. `diskpar.exe` was a standalone utility released at the time of Windows 2000. It still works with Windows 7 and 8.

Answer (score 1):

WMI (wmic command) is available in Windows XP (SP3 or may be even early) (as a diskpart.exe btw).
So in Windows XP you can use as Msinfo32 as Wmic to check offset.
1024K offset is the best choice for SDD and 4k disks or RAID.